# Logout user from the previous session if he login with another session

Tags: session

We have an requirement where we want user to have only one session enable at a time in the web application. If the user is trying to login from another machiine, their previous session should get expired and should be logged out. 
Any lead on this would be appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by application? Is there some custom app in your SP, or do you mean generally in SP? Which version of SP?

Comment: web application, and we are working on SP 2013

Comment: It depends a bit on your configured authentication settings, but there are some options based on custom solutions, such as http://www.sharepoint4developers.net/en-nz/post/limit-session-account.aspx.

Comment: This is for form based authentication. I'm not using FBA.

Comment: Yeah well, it would be strongly advised to detail everything that's missing in the initial question by editing it. Don't expect us to fill the blank holes.

Comment: @moe : What else information is required ?